# Having Multiple Files for a Code, will not slow down the code?

Tags: performance, file

I am new to programming, I have in past coded bunch of discord bots, and even in discord bots, you have to create a separate folder and add all "command" files in it, so there were different files for each different commands in a folder separate from main code.

I was wondering if the main code is accessing the different file of code in a different folder, wont he take a bit of time, even if its very very tiny, it will right? so that means its way better to write all the code in a single file so it will be faster for the code itself?

I am pretty sure am wrong, but I really hope someone replies lol

Thank you!

Comment: Which language are we talking about? But generally... dont even bother with such things. Even if it's an interpreting language, the code from different files would probably be cached on the first use.

Comment: oh so like, when the main code has started, it will cache all the other files code? i dont think it will do it automatically...so we will have to code so it caches all the required files, right...

Comment: No. You know there're compilers that translate your written code into machine code (or byte code) and interpreters which... interprete and execute the code, right? They will do all necessary things for you.

Comment: ok so basically, main code accessing codes from different files, wont take any kind of time right? like there wont be any delay in accessing code right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.